# Is it good idea to set DNS server adress from different providers on DSL router?

Tags: dns, adsl-router

Is it good idea to set DNS server address from different providers on DSL router?

Lets say set google DNS address for Primary DNS server and Cloudflare DNS server for secondary DNS server.

is it good idea?

IF i want set a public DNS service is it ok to set from 2 different providers?

Comment: I usually check the Gibson Research DNS Benchmark utility every year or so, and make note of the best performing DNS servers provided by entities I don't actively distrust, and configure for them. https://www.grc.com/dns/benchmark.htm

Answer (score 3):

It's always good to have a secondary DNS server.

However, usually if the DNS supplied by the ISP is good enough,
or there is no other problem, there is no need to change it.
The ISP is after all the closest to you physically (internet-speaking),
so may be the fastest to answer, in order to speed up your internet surfing.

Comment: +1 Best advice. So many people seem to think there's some kind of competition to find the "best" DNS server, when it's almost always the ISP default.

Comment: Agreed, from a performance perspective, but ISP DNS resolution can be a problem from a privacy perspective in a way other revolvers aren't, since they can't effortlessly join the queries emitting from your IP to a IRL name and address. DoH and DoT are effectively useless if they are resolving against the ISP servers. the whole point of them is to prevent inspection of the query by network operators like the ISP.

Comment: @FrankThomas: Only a VPN can help in that.

Comment: DoH and DoT use encryption to protect the query, simmilar to a VPN tunnel, though if you are implying that the crypto is not quite as good, and the handshake process is a little more open to manipulation and substitution attacks than VPN handshake when performed by a party very close to the client, you are correct.

Comment: IF i want set a public DNS service is it ok to set from 2 different providers?

Comment: Yes, no problem.

Comment: @paymanz Depends on your OS and setup. Secondary DNS isn't necessarily a fallback resolver. Primary and secondary could be used in a round-robin fashion. It shouldn't be a problem 99,99% of the time.